# How to filter data based on maximum datetime value in each day

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

Ex:

```
 ID Name Age Salary ClicksAsofToday  Timestamp
```

---

```
 1. Arun  25 25000    5               Aug,20 10.50pm
 2. Arun  25 2000     8               Aug,20 10.55pm
 3. Arun  25 25000    13              Aug,20 11.00pm
 4. Vijay 25 20000    2               Aug,20 10.50pm
 5. Vijay 25 20000    3               Aug,20 10.55pm
 6. Vijay 25 20000    8               Aug,20 11.00pm
 7. Vijay 25 20000    3               Aug,21 10.55pm
 8. Vijay 25 20000    8               Aug,21 12.00pm
```

I want the result as

```
 ID Name Age Salary  ClicksAsofToday  Timestamp
```

---

```
 1. Arun  25 25000    13              Aug,20 11.00pm (Max time of that Particular date)
 2. Vijay 25 20000    8               Aug,20 11.00pm
 8. Vijay 25 20000    8               Aug,21 12.00pm (Max time of another date)
```

Timestamp column is of type `DateTime`

Comment: What is the type of the timestamp column? DateTime or what? Does your list contain data from multiple dates(Aug 20, Aug 21) and you want to get data for each day or does it contain only per day data?

Comment: Ya it is DateTime type and the data contains multiple date's, Its kinda History table.

Comment: Few points: 1. You've done decent job showing your original data and desired data, but it was only partial - you haven't said anything about getting data for each day 2. You haven't shown anything you tried 3. You haven't given [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would have allowed anybody to test their queries against the given data. That's why you've got so many downvotes. When you will ask your new questions try not  to forget these problems with your first question - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If not, you have to clarify the question for sure.

Comment: @Eugene, thanks for your answer. I used part of your answer and got the result:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

```
public class Data
{
    public String Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Data(String name, DateTime timeStamp)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.TimeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} at {1}", this.Name, this.TimeStamp);
    }
}
```

You can use:

```
var source = new Data[]
{
    new Data("Yesterday early", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)),
    new Data("Yesterday middle", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(2)),
    new Data("Yesterday middle", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(2)),
    new Data("Yesterday late", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(3)),

    new Data("Today early", DateTime.Today),
    new Data("Today middle", DateTime.Today.AddHours(2)),
    new Data("Today late 1", DateTime.Today.AddHours(3)),
    new Data("Today late 2", DateTime.Today.AddHours(3)),

    new Data("Tomorrow early", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)),
    new Data("Tomorrow middle", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(2)),
    new Data("Tomorrow late 1", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(3)),
    new Data("Tomorrow late 2", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(3)),
};


var lateInDays = source.
    GroupBy((data) => data.TimeStamp.Date).
    Select(dayGroup =>
        new 
        {
            DayGroup = dayGroup, 
            MaxTimeInDay = dayGroup.Max(data => data.TimeStamp)
        }).
    SelectMany((dayGroupWithMaxTime) =>
        dayGroupWithMaxTime.
            DayGroup.
            Where(data =>
                (data.TimeStamp == dayGroupWithMaxTime.MaxTimeInDay)));
```

This is far from optimal, but it works.

**How it works:**

**1.** `GroupBy((data) => data.TimeStamp.Date).`  - Groups your data items by their date( for three days there is three groups)

**2.** Part:

```
 Select(dayGroup =>
        new 
        {
            DayGroup = dayGroup, 
            MaxTimeInDay = dayGroup.Max(data => data.TimeStamp)
        }).
```

Augments each of three by-day groups with information about their maximal time in day(actually with full DateTime, so you may want to use DateTime.TimeOfDay property instead of full DateTime)

**3.** Part

```
 SelectMany((dayGroupWithMaxTime) =>
        dayGroupWithMaxTime.
            DayGroup.
            Where(data =>
                (data.TimeStamp == dayGroupWithMaxTime.MaxTimeInDay)));
```

From each group(for each day) selects all record with maximal time in day, just simply comparing each record's TimeStamp with maximal in day(for his current group(day)):

```
 dayGroupWithMaxTime.
     DayGroup.
     Where(data =>
               (data.TimeStamp == dayGroupWithMaxTime.MaxTimeInDay))
```